# not sure what to test exactly in white box testing, is it each function?

Tags: php, testing

this is probably the wrong place to ask but i searched and couldn't find an answer, i have a website, i want to do white box testing, first of all i don't know what type of white box testing i should use, should i use line coverage? or branch coverage? and what exactly is tested? is it each function by it's own? what if there's an if statement not in a function? is me choosing a function to test is unit testing?

my code has multiple classes and multiple functions in each class, there's a handler page that calls each class function based on what form was submitted, should i test the handler page too?

handler page

```
switch ($_POST['formSubmit']) {
    
case 'complete-regP':

$passenger = new LogRegValidation();
$passenger->userInfoValidate();

break;
```

logRegValidation class

```
function userInfoValidate();
{
//code
}

function  function loginValidate()
{
//code
}
```

Comment: **White-box testing** is a method of software testing that tests internal structures or workings of an application, as opposed to its functionality (i.e. black-box testing).

Comment: hey, can you be more specific? should i test each function by it's own?